# Custom taxonomy escaping html attr

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy, really simple one.
When inputing  tag to the description it works fine and as expected.
however when adding `rel="nofollow"` or `rel=nofollow` wp is dismissing the attr and save the a tag only with the href attr.

(the same for target=_blank)

any ideas?

BTW the auto XHTML flag in writing setting is off.

--Edit--

1. registered new taxonomy:

   ```
   $labels = array(
   'name'                => _x( 'funders', 'taxonomy general name' ),
   'singular_name'       => _x( 'funder', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
   'search_items'        => __( 'search funder' ),
   'all_items'           => __( 'all funders' ),
   'parent_item'         => __( 'funder parent' ),
   'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'funder parent:' ),
   'edit_item'           => __( 'edit funder' ), 
   'update_item'         => __( 'update funder' ),
   'add_new_item'        => __( 'add funder' ),
   'new_item_name'       => __( 'funder name' ),
   'menu_name'           => __( 'Funder' )
   ```

   `);`
   `$args = array(
       'hierarchical'        => true,
       'labels'              => $labels,
       'show_ui'             => true,
       'show_admin_column'   => true,
       'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
       'query_var'           => true,
       'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'funder' )
   );`

   `register_taxonomy( 'funder', array( 'post' ), $args );`
2. added a term:
   name -> foo
   slug -> bar
   description->`<a rel=nofollow target=_blank href="www.foo.com">bar</a>`
3. save

when viewing the term or edit it, I get:
name -> foo
slug -> bar
description->`<a href="www.foo.com">bar</a>`

hope is clearer now.

Comment: nothing is clear to me and most probably others too..

Comment: It is echoing as plain html in front end? Also, you are missing ending single quote in both 'funders' and 'funder'. EDIT: try escaping the "s `<a href=\"##\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">bar</a>`

Comment: the missing ending single quote is copy paste mistake, I have it in the original file.
the echoing is not yet the problem, I can see that the attrs are dismissed in edit term page.
tried to escape as well with no luck.